# Drawbacks of participating in a conference boycott

Tags: conference

There is a petition going round at the moment regarding not attending US conferences. It has been signed by many academics. In theory I would like to sign, but doesn't doing so shoot the academic in the foot by not contributing to conferences and therefore their field [in the case that the conference cannot be relocated]?

I include the link below for the interest of others who may want to:

[Link](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeNN_2HHREt1h-dm_CgWpFHw8NDPGLCkOwB4lLRFtKFJqI25w/viewform)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52869/discussion-on-question-by-c26-drawbacks-of-participating-in-a-conference-boycott).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

**Yes**, participating in such a boycott can come at a personal cost.  That is true for any boycott; the existence of this cost is what makes the boycott worthwhile in the first place.  If there was no cost at signing such a pledge, it would be much less impressive if many people sign.

However, again as with any boycott, as [O. R. Mapper says](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/84143/proposed-conference-veto-in-the-us#comment210169_84143), the marginal cost of participating drops if more academics participate.  Indeed, if a very large number of academics participate in a boycott, organisers may relocate or cancel the event, which brings your cost of boycotting, compared to people who chose not to boycott, to zero.

Comment: @C26 Also, how much it costs you also highly depends on which conferences you typically go to, and what alternative conferences there are and where they stand in relation. For example, if you typically go only to European conferences, or if you typically go to the US but there's a European one of equivalent stature, boycotting US conferences isn't too big of deal. Contrariwise, if the US conferences are the important ones in your field and there is nothing comparable in Europe/Asia/etc., then the boycott might hurt you quite a lot.

Comment: The cost also depends on where on your career you are. It is relatively higher for young researchers than for people already established in their community.

Comment: Is signing the petition binding ? If not you could sign, and if the number of participants for the petition is not high enough, you could still participate in the conference.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful I doubt anyone will stop you if you go anyway, but people might ask why you sign a promise and then break it.

Comment: Well, it's like planning an event, and then canceling because noone signed up to attend. In this case the event would be the boycott of an event.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful who is the controlling legal authority? Trump.  I doubt he is going to stop you, especially if one of his Trump Hotels is hosting the conference.